# Send POST request from Android to Symfony backend

Tags: android, symfony, post, backend

I try to send POST requests (like forms) from my Android application to my Symfony backend but when I hit the 'Send' button for example, an Android FileNotFoundException ('http://192.168.1.84/1day-symfony/web/app_dev.php/api/request') is thrown. Maybe it is caused by the rewritten URL.
I do not know how to fix it...

Comment: Where is that Send button? You should post your code. What do you mean by 'rewritten url'?

Comment: The send button is in my app and the URL on my Apache logs appears to be rewritten from http://192.168.1.84/1day-symfony/app_dev.php/api/request to http://192.168.1.84/1day-symfony/api/request

Comment: In your app? Where? In a WebView?

Comment: Copy and past your code please! try starting symfony web server and try again: `php app/console server:start 192.168.1.84:8000` and post data to `192.168.1.84:8000/api/request`

Comment: Code is confidential. I have a webserver started because I said I use Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Volley fixes the issue of the rewritten URLs.